# Snowflake Warehouse: Can the MAX WH size be capped?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is it possible to specify the maximum size of a warehouse?

We want to be able to give users the flexibility to size up their warehouse, within limits.  For our environment it's unlikely query performance will improve much when going from a MEDIUM to XX-Large warehouse.  Yet our users tend to error on the high side, not the low one, resulting in high compute costs.

I know we can limit the number of clusters in a warehouse and we can implement a credit based quota on a warehouse (or account) using a resource monitor, but I'd really like to start with limiting the max size a WH can be set to in the first place.

I'm thinking it could be one more parameter of the WH, such as MAX_SIZE = 'M'.

Thanks,

Comment: I've gotten around this by creating different sized warehouses, and giving users access to those warehouses. So I'll give someone access to XS,S,M warehouses.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming there is a role (e.g., SYSADMIN) that creates all warehouses or has modify privileges. Create this procedure with that role and then any user can call this SP passing the warehouse name and desired size.  Since the SP executes as owner (vs. caller), the user calling the SP doesn't need to have MODIFY privileges on the warehouse, just their role must have usage rights on the SP.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE utl.arch_set_wh_size_sp(P_WH_NM VARCHAR, P_WH_SIZE VARCHAR)
/****************************************************************************************\
  DESC: set WH size

  YY-MM-DD WHO          CHANGE DESCRIPTION
  -------- ------------ ----------------------------------------------------------------
  19-12-13 eroesch      Initial design
\****************************************************************************************/
  RETURNS STRING
  LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS $$
  var result = "";
  var sqlCmd = "";
  var sqlStmt = "";
  var rs = "";
  var curSize = "";
  var whSizesAllowed = ["X-SMALL", "XSMALL", "SMALL", "MEDIUM"];

  try {
    // first validate the warehouse exists and get the current size
    sqlCmd = "SHOW WAREHOUSES LIKE '" + P_WH_NM + "'";
    sqlStmt = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: sqlCmd} );
    rs = sqlStmt.execute();

    if (sqlStmt.getRowCount() == 0) {
      throw new Error('No Warehouse Found by that name');
    } else {
      rs.next();
      curSize = rs.getColumnValue('size').toUpperCase();
    }

    // next validate the new size is in the acceptable range
    if (whSizesAllowed.indexOf(P_WH_SIZE.toUpperCase()) == -1) {
      throw new Error('Not a valid Warehouse size');
    };

    // set Warehouse size
    sqlCmd = "ALTER WAREHOUSE " + P_WH_NM + " SET WAREHOUSE_SIZE = :1";
    sqlStmt = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: sqlCmd, binds: [P_WH_SIZE]} );
    sqlStmt.execute();

    result = "Resized Warehouse " + P_WH_NM + " from: " + curSize + " to: " + P_WH_SIZE.toUpperCase();
  }
  catch (err) {
    if (err.code === undefined) {
      result = err.message
    } else {
      result =  "Failed: Code: " + err.code + " | State: " + err.state;
      result += "\n  Message: " + err.message;
      result += "\nStack Trace:\n" + err.stackTraceTxt; 
      result += "\nParam:\n" + P_WH_NM + ", " + P_WH_SIZE;
    }
  }
  return result;
$$;
```

Comment: Thanks Erick.  I like your style...  I will let you know if I end up "borrowing" your content.  Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is No, you cannot put a cap on the size of a warehouse.

A longer answer is to build a process for resetting your warehouse sizes to whatever you deem as their "default" size on a given interval.

Comment: Thanks.  Clarity is a good thing.  This seems like a reasonable feature request.  Someone had a multi-point feature request already... so I just added another vote for it.  If you think this feature has merit please vote for it.  https://support.snowflake.net/s/ideas?t=1531953141811

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier workaround for this that I learned earlier today:

```
-- On a given WH, grant create to the user (or ROLE) you want to have provisioned for access
GRANT USAGE ON WAREHOUSE my_warehouse TO my_user;

-- Then remove the privileges that would allow them to alter the WH from the default it is beholden to:
REVOKE MODIFY ON WAREHOUSE my_warehouse FROM my_user;
-- NOTE: this retains the ability for the USER/ROLE to use (i.e. USAGE) the WH.
```

Granted, it doesn't stop another ROLE/USER from altering the WH, then having this ROLE/USER come behind it... However, with the proper care in access controls in your env, this will get you to a place of authority on the subject of throttling a WH.

Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

While not a perfect solution, you can ask your SE to set the parameter WAREHOUSE_MAX_SIZE to limit the size of warehouses that users in your account can provision.

On request, I have capped the size of warehouses for at least one of my customers using this method and it works just fine.

Comment: I don't see any documentation on this option - have searched for WAREHOUSE_MAX_SIZE with no luck.

Comment: Yes, some parameters are internal to Snowflake, but your SE can set them.